# Comparing power consumption of different FPGAs

Tags: fpga, power-dissipation

I want to compare power dissipation of FPGAs from different vendors, the I/O count and the logic resource shall be matched as close as possible when choosing the FPGAs.

I want to create a trivial design that would utilize a big chunk of the logic resource and the I/O pins. This design shall be implemented across the different FPGAs and the power dissipation shall be measured on each power rail.

The problem as it exists is that, there is no simple way to create a design for this. The design being sought does not need to do anything productive but merely needs to implement switching activity, it should just occupy say X% of resource inside an FPGA and this number can be specified as amount of LUTs also.

Is there a standard way to produce such a design that would have huge amount of logic which keeps switching and helps us make the power measurements? I do not think any standard method to create design of such nature exists.

Comment: Have you considered bitcoin mining?

Comment: No. I just need a "trivial" design which does not get synthesized away. The design itself does not matter at all. What matters is that it produce a lot of switching activity which then helps us make our measurements.

Comment: Exaclty, you need an operation that is an immense amount of work, that produces a small result which plausibly enough depends on all of that work.  And even better if there's already an FPGA-ish implementation out there.  Brute force crypto related things are great for that - mining (but not for profit), key cracking (of non-messages), etc.

Comment: I don't think any single design is going to do what you want. You need a variety of different designs...designs with lots of pipelining, designs with long adders/multipliers, designs with different clock domains, and so forth. You need designs that are scalable so you can separate static power from logic switching power. How will you compare architectures with hard macros, such as multipliers, to those without? This is a really hard problem.

Comment: I have an idea that if a "standard" design exists that can just be compiled on different tools then it will give us a good idea how different their power consumption is

Comment: Using a "standard" design assumes that all FPGAs have a "standard" architecture. They don't. You might as well talk about designing a standard driving test that you would use for bicycles, SUVs, trucks, electric cars, skateboards,...

Comment: The basic idea is that, we have a design and we implement it across different FPGAs without any FPGA specific optimizations and then look at the result. I had expected this to be easier than what it has turned out to be so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce an unbiased report on performance comparison of FPGAs from different vendors you need to care not only about "the I/O count and the logic resource", each of which you are going to match "as close as possible when choosing the FPGAs". The FPGA architecture -- how LUTs are aggregated into logic elements, in particular -- can be a game changer when comparing against selected applications. If your understanding of matching "logic resource" embraces details of the logic block implementation solutions, the gamut of vendors under test is narrowed, sometimes to a single vendor. If you refer to "the logic resource" as a coarse quantification of LUTs per chip or even a transistor logic gate count parameter, you may end comparing the efficiency of FPGA development tools for selected applications, not hardware.

All these said, the power performance measurements of FPGA designs is anything but an uncultivated land. See a review of [GPU vs FPGA Performance Comparison](http://www.bertendsp.com/pdf/whitepaper/BWP001_GPU_vs_FPGA_Performance_Comparison_v1.0.pdf) for applications as diverse as image processing, cloud computing, wideband communications, Big Data, robotics, high-definition video. An article "[TinySDR: Low-Power SDR Platform](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/nsdi20-paper-hessar.pdf)" presents a detailed report on testbed development for SDR and IoT implementations. Pay attention to a github reference in this article.

Studying references from searches for "*testbeds for fpga power consumption*" may give you ideas for your research, if not satisfying the request of your SE question in full. Or, perhaps, it will convince you to modify your research subject.